# Migration requests: [stackoverflow] posts on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration

I started going through all the [open questions on SO tagged [stackoverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[stackoverflow]+closed%3A0), and retagging those that involved *real* stack overflows as [stack-overflow]. However, there are many SO-related questions in there that need to be migrated, which requires the involvement of more 3k+ users, or a moderator. Help please? :)

<sub>PS. interesting markdown bug: the link does not show up in the preview, although it does appear properly in the final posted version.</sub>

Comment: ...Not to mention that there is a limit of 12 close votes per day (which is incorrectly phrased as "Closure votes" in the error message).

Comment: Done - I'm out now as well though.

Comment: Need to get a moderator involved.