# Interesting stackoverflow searches

Tags: discussion, questions, search, moderation

What are some of the common searches you use, or searches that you can act on immediately?

For instance,

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+[subjective]+closed%3A0

Finds questions tagged subjective that have no answers and are still open.  Some of them are probably worthwhile closing, others may be worth answering, etc.

What searches do you find useful, either in terms of answering them, or in cleaning up and improving SO?

Answer (score 3):

Since we only get 12 close votes a day, I have a lot of searches bookmarked that I iterate through when I'm bored:

- [tagged "stackoverflow" and open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bstackoverflow%5d+closed%3A0) (see this recent [support request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37562/migration-requests-stackoverflow-posts-on-so))
- [tagged "belongs-on-superuser" and open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[belongs-on-superuser]+closed%3A0) (zero remaining at the moment)
- [tagged "belongs-on-serverfault" and open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[belongs-on-serverfault]+closed%3A0) (also recently down to zero)
- [tagged "not-programming-related" and open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[not-programming-related]+closed%3A0)

I also have a few "problem users" that I regularly monitor in case a question needs to be flagged or closed (e.g. see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23404/whats-the-deal-with-user-shore) and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27946/endless-question-user-what-to-do), although I shouldn't list the actual users I watch in case someone gets offended).

Comment: I decided not to maintain a file or paper list of troublemakers. Instead I try to remember them and check on their recent activity when I notice them. The hope is that if they shape up, I'll grow ever less annoyed by them until I forget that they were ever on the list. Thus rewarding their new found community spirit. Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the search Jeff says they use to look at the feature-request list:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request+-status-declined+-status-deferred&sort=votes

Though I usually use this one to look at that list:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request+-status-declined+-status-deferred+-status-completed&sort=votes