# Suggest Posting on Meta to users tagging a question "stackoverflow"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Obviously some [questions tagged stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) are about actual overflowing stacks, but many of them aren't (look through the list - many, if not most, are closed).

Would it be useful to popup a message saying "If you're asking a question about the site, please ask it on Meta" with a link to Meta?

Answer (score 2):

I like it, you can't never go wrong when helping new users.

I would add that there's some reputation threshold when this doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: I don't know about the rep cap thing - the person who asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370202/just-wonder-what-does-rg-near-performance-and-sql-server-tags-mean-closed has >4000 rep. Where would you set the bar? How often have you asked questions tagged stackoverflow? Would it really annoy you that much?

Comment: No, not really... I never asked a stackoverflow (programming) question

Comment: @Dominic: Surprising in a 4k user, but I'd set the bar at 10k. If you don't have a clue by then, no amount of prompting is going to give you one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'd set the bar lower at say 1k or 2k. Sure, there are people with high rep who mistakenly ask it on SO _only because they've never had the need to go to MSO_. And if they have 1k/2k rep, they've been in the system long enough to realize their mistake after one notification.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a [retag discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37562/migration-requests-stackoverflow-posts-on-so) a while back on this.

IMHO, [stackoverflow] should refer to the site, and [stack-overflow] and [stack-overflow-exception] should refer to the buffer overrun condition.

Comment: What if you were asking a question about how to implement something similar to stackoverflow.com?

Comment: I've been leaving those questions alone so far, but IMO most of them would have still been perfectly valid questions if they simply hadn't mentioned SO at all.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea. I like [@Juan Manuel's refinement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41001/suggest-posting-on-meta-to-users-tagging-a-question-stackoverflow/41005#41005), though; after a certain point (10k? certainly not just 1k), you can be pretty sure asking them this question is just a nuisance.